# Active Directory Authentication and login.... C#

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

Just a quick question after reviewing MSDN information and information found around here Active Directory Authentication seems relativly simple but extremely complicated at the same time...

I have a simple function call to authenticate the user up front. My question is will this keep them logged in while the program is running or am I missing a key component.

```
domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Fabrikam", "ou=TechWriters,dc=fabrikam,dc=com");
isValidated = install.domainContext.ValidateCredentials(uName, pWord);
 if (isValidated)
        {
             //processing info here
        }
```

By logged in, I define that as the ability to execute 1 program stored on the network share, and download 1-27 other installers locatted on a seperate share under the same AD authentication

Comment: The question is how do you define "logged in".

Comment: Good point, Ill update above, but basically The program will need access to download installers from the network share.and execute one on the network share